# How to get spiders to group together in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have two cave spider spawners that are very close to each other, so I'm trying to make a trap for them.

I have all the spiders funnel into a 1x1 vertical tube, that's 3 high, with an iron bar on the bottom.

But, the spiders get into the tube, and hang at the top, with one going to the bottom.

Is there a design with the current AI, that gets the spiders to bunch up?

Comment: Could you not add flowing water to force them along?

Comment: Nope, spiders can walk up streams, it helps "nudge" them, but if they don't want to get pushed, they can avoid it.

Comment: They can't walk up streams; they're grabbing the walls instead. Make the stream wider and they won't have nearby walls to grab, or roof the stream tube so they can't get above the water (but be careful you don't make it so long they drown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spiders require a different grinder design than most mobs, as they can climb walls. The path they take from the spawn rooms to the actual grinder cannot go down, it must always flow either level or upwards. Water should be used to push them along to the end. Here is an excellent tutorial on making a dual cave spider grinder, which I have personally used to great effect.